# compiler error in MS visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am compiling my C source code in MS visual Studio C++ 2010.I am getting following following errors while building. What can be the reasons for it?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/time.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'suseconds_t'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/time.h(19): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/time.h(37): error C2079: 'it_interval' uses undefined struct 'timeval'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/time.h(38): error C2079: 'it_value' uses undefined struct 'timeval'
```

[EDIT ]

Following is the code in my program:

```
   #ifndef _DWORD_DEFINED
   #define _DWORD_DEFINED
   typedef unsigned long DWORD;
   #endif



      int getTime(struct timeval * tp, void * tzp)
        {
        DWORD milliseconds;

        milliseconds = timeGetTime();

        tp->tv_sec = milliseconds / 1000;
        tp->tv_usec = (milliseconds % 1000) * 1000;

       return 0;
        }
```

Comment: You could go one step further and ask a question like this: "My program doesn't work, please help" without providing us any code...

Comment: What Armen is trying to tell you is that you forgot to post the code that causes the error. Visual Studio is giving you the individual **line numbers** and **files** responsible for the error. Click the "edit" link below your post and copy and paste those into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, all I can say is this:

- The first error cause is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yha416c7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
- The second error cause is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
- The third and fourth error cause is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ekhdcxs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Edit: After the OP's edit, the errors are more than obvious. Look at the `struct timeval`.
Where is it's definition? You access members of that struct and still you there is no visible definition of the struct.

Comment: **time.h** is the external  header file i am using.Do you think I need to edit that header file? Can you please make me little bit clear on it?I had searched those errors and got also those solutions, but i  didn't think editing standard header file is good idea.

Comment: @thetna: Ah, you want me to be more specific, do you? I am shocked! No, you don't want to edit any standard header, but I can't tell you what's wrong without any code.

Comment: @Armen,I have posted the snippet of the code frm header file .could you please have a look on it and suggest me some solution?

Comment: @thetna: I don't need a snippet from time.h I need snippet from YOUR code

Comment: @Armen, Thanks for your answer. But, i am not still sure, what can i do to remove those errors.Can you give me some more ideas?

Comment: @thetna: In whichever header timeval struct is defined, include that header into WTypes.h